# How to remove spacing between UITableViewCell with UINavigationController in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a UITableViewController with a UINavigationController added to it. This is part of of an UITabBar. I have to add the UINavigationController to add a segue from the UITableViewCell, but when I do, I get some weird offset from the search bar in my UITableView. I have tried to remove the status bar and navigation bar in storyboard, but when I run the app, the offset is still there.

I've included some images to clarify this more.

[image: preview]

This is how my storyBoard looks:

[image: storyboard]

Since I prefer to keep my code as clean as possible, I'd like some solution where I don't need to add any code, but if that's no option then that's okay as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" on your view controller's attribute inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Attribute Inspector for your TableView, if you change the "Separator Insets" from "Default" to "Custom" then you'll see the default includes a 15px margin that you can change.

[image]